# Is it possible to override/replace an event subscriber?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I would like to replace an event subscriber.

Can I write a class that implements `EventSubscriberInterface` which  replaces another event subscriber?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since an event subscriber is a service, you can achieve it by creating a class that implements [`ServiceModifierInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21ServiceModifierInterface.php/interface/ServiceModifierInterface/8.9.x).

Drupal doesn't have a class that alters an event subscriber (which isn't a class used in tests). Changing the class associated to an even subscriber isn't different from changing the class associated with a generic service, which is what the following code used from the [`CoreServiceProvider`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21CoreServiceProvider.php/class/CoreServiceProvider/8.9.x) class does, in its [`alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21CoreServiceProvider.php/function/CoreServiceProvider%3A%3Aalter/8.9.x) method.

```php
$uuid_service = $container->getDefinition('uuid');

// Debian/Ubuntu uses the (broken) OSSP extension as their UUID
// implementation. The OSSP implementation is not compatible with the
// PECL functions.
if (function_exists('uuid_create') && !function_exists('uuid_make')) {
  $uuid_service->setClass('Drupal\\Component\\Uuid\\Pecl');
}
elseif (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
  $uuid_service->setClass('Drupal\\Component\\Uuid\\Com');
}
```

[`$container->getDefinition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21dependency-injection%21ContainerBuilder.php/function/ContainerBuilder%3A%3AgetDefinition/8.9.x) returns a [`Definition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21dependency-injection%21Definition.php/class/Definition/8.9.x) instance.